# SQL joining two tables with a LEFTJOIN

Tags: mysql

I have tables

- table_order
- product_name

Below is the SQL I have to query `table_order` which works perfectly in outputting the product_id but I need it to show it's name and not number.  I need to modify mySQL with a `LEFTJOIN` to somehow connect with table `product_name` but I keep getting an error.  So instead of

99 = 15, 99 = 16

I need

99 = name1, 99 = name2

```
SELECT table_order.order_id, table_order.product_id
              FROM table_order 
              WHERE table_order.order_id=99
              ORDER BY table_order.order_product_id


table table_order
_________________________
order_id  |  product_id |
_________________________
99        |  15         |
99        |  16         |
_________________________

table product_name
___________________________
product_id |  product_name |
___________________________
15         |  name1        |
16         |  name2        |
___________________________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables, as you say, on product_id.

```
SELECT table_order.order_id, product_name.product_name
FROM table_order 
    INNER JOIN product_name on table_order.product_id = product_name.product_id
WHERE table_order.order_id=99
ORDER BY table_order.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT a.product_id, b.product_name
   FROM table_order AS a LEFT JOIN product_name AS b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
   WHERE a.order_id = '99'
   ORDER BY a.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.product_id,t2.product_name from table_order as t1
  inner join(
    select * from product_name
  ) as t2
  on t1.product_id = t2.product_name
  where t1.product_id = //some Number
```

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to output all the orders regardless of whether the product id of that table_order has a connection to product_table, you need to use LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT o.order_id, p.product_name
   FROM table_order o
      LEFT JOIN product_name p  ON o.product_id = p.product_id  
   ORDER BY o.product_id
```

However if you just need to get all the rows that exists in both tables, you can use an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT o.order_id, p.product_name
   FROM table_order o
      INNER JOIN product_name p  ON o.product_id = p.product_id  
   ORDER BY o.product_id
```